# Update postgres field with results from another query

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have table with following format.

```
Moderations table
+---------+------------+--------------+
| mod_id  | post_id    | is_moderated |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  1      |    1       |    true      |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  2      |    2       |    false     |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  1      |    3       |    false     |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  3      |    4       |    false     |
+---------+------------+--------------+
|  4      |    5       |    false     |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```

I have another table that tracks whether a particular mod is active.

```
Moderator Table
+---------+---------------+
| mod_id  | is_mod_active |
+---------+---------------+
|  1      |     true      |
+---------+---------------+
|  2      |     false     |
+---------+---------------+
|  3      |     false     |
+---------+---------------+
|  4      |     true      |
+---------+---------------+
```

I perform following query to get the moderation requests that are unmoderated, and for whom assigned moderator has gone inactive.

```
SELECT * 
from 
    moderation 
left join moderator 
    on mod_id=user_id 
where 
    is_mod_active = false and 
    is_moderated = false
order by 
created_on
```

for these selected rows I would like to update the mod_id field with following query

```
SELECT mod_id 
FROM 
    moderator
WHERE
    is_mod_active = true
```

The second query will be shorter or longer than the first query. Is there a way to update this?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: I want to update the first table. In this case we see that unmoderated posts are assigned to 2 and 3 but they aren't available. So these should be assigned to 1 and 4

Comment: Where does the column `is_mod_available` come from?

Comment: This is unclear; you didn't specify how the moderations should be assigned to the moderators.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe they can be assigned serially based on created_on field (in the moderations table)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have corrected it

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe They should be assigned in order of creation. Say they are created in order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and we want to assign moderators (A, B) then assignment should be ((1, A),(2, B),(3, A),(4, B),(5, A),(6, B)) and so on.

Comment: I see no `created_on`. And "serially" leaves me clueless...